# Binding function with parameters in html class in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have html element:

```
<div style="grid-column: span 1">
```

I would like to use function to determine span size:
I try something like this, but it doesn't render.

```
:style="{ 'grid-column: span': getColumnSize('string') }"
```

what is correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

use `computed` method. in computed method you can write a function that return your style as an object. then use it in your html.

```html
<div :style="getColumnSize"></div>
```

```js
computed: {
  getColumnSize() {
    return {
      gridColumn: 'span 1'
    }
  }
}
```

note: you should use camel case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```html
<div :style="{ 'grid-column': `span ${getColumnSize('string')}` }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would store the value of span in data then place the value in style like this

```
<div :style="`grid-column : span ${spanValue}`"> new div with grid</div>
```